# Looking for PHP BPMN 2.0 and service bus 'esb'

Tags: php, esb, bpmn

Does anyone know a BPMN 2.0 designer/modeler and process execution engine based on PHP? In the same context, does anyone know an ESB accepting PHP script?

Comment: I don't see a reason, why this question should be down-voted.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know a BPMN 2.0 designer/modeler and process execution
>   engine based on PHP?

You could use probably almost every PHP framework like symfony to build some ESB functionality into your application but it generaly seems a bit odd to build an ESB in PHP. I don't think PHP is the right technology to that kind of architecture since PHP was developed to be a front end tool. This brings limitation like the lack of non-blocking execution, timeout problems, complicated handling of asynchronus processes.

> In the same context, does anyone know an ESB accepting PHP script?

So my recommendation would be:

1. Check if you *really* need an ESB *
2. If you do, choose one among the stable systems, e.g. http://www.jboss.org/jbpm or http://www.mulesoft.org/
3. Integrate your PHP script as a service using webservices.

* An ESB is not something you can drop in like a jQuery Script so better think twice here.

Related question: 
[PHP and ESB (with Mule) (ESB: Enterprise Service Bus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975606/php-and-esb-with-mule-esb-enterprise-service-bus)

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a mix of the camunda BPM tools (which all are open source).

The camunda BPM platform with camunda BPM PHP SDK or your own PHP solution via REST API and camunda BPM javascript renderer would provide the process execution and rendering of diagrams for e.g. monitoring purposes.

The camunda BPM modeler (Eclipse Plugin) deals with the modeling/design aspect.

You can find all these tools [here](https://github.com/camunda/)

Answer (score 0):

While not a BPMN suite, at least a bit of Workflow is part of [ezComponents](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/latest/introduction_Workflow.html).

Please be aware, that ezComponents recently failed to get an Apache project after staying some time in incubator...